# OpenGL light not shining quad

Tags: opengl, lighting

I've constructed a scene using OpenGL/GLUT with a spot light but I'm getting troubles with light shining some of the walls

[image]

what is going on and how to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing any shader code and vertex setup, this is difficult to answer. But I suspect that you have winded the quads of the left wall clockwise instead of counterclockwise, or vise versa. Or you didn't specify the normals correctly.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a hint to solve it and in fact I was drawing clockwise and the normal was inverted, giving me odd results. Thanks you!

Comment: GLUT doesn't support shaders. Just saying